# Why are nava grahas in a temple placed such?

Tags: temple, navagraha

When we visit a navagraha mandapa(where the nine planets are placed) in a temple, we observe a distinct placement of the planets. No planet faces other planet. But in reality, a planet faces other planet at some point of time.

[image].

Is there a reason why these planets are placed such in temples?